# Covert to custom numeric format strings in ASP.NET MVC / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to custom numeric format strings ASP.NET MVC SQL Server.

***Achieved Results:***
111345111.2233

***Required Results:***
111,345,111.223300

**Index.aspx Code**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>
```

**Index.aspx.cs Code**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT sum(book_stock) from alpha_tbl;", con);
            
Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Don't do this in your query. Formatting belongs in the presentation layer, not the data layer. Add some custom formatting to your control or format the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var x = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Label1.Text = x.ToString("N6");
```

First convert object to decimal.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyqpGV

Comment: I tried already it gives the error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 Arguments

Comment: I need to bind data from sql, fyi

Comment: cmd.ExecuteScalar() should return an object, just store this object in a variable, then convert it to string and assign it to label.text.

Comment: If you're plan is to do two way binding then you will need a way more sophisticated approach than the one you're proposing here.

Comment: I have tried already and it gives same error    var test = cmd.ExecuteScalar();      Label1.Text = test.ToString("N6");

Comment: Which .Net version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022, mvc asp.net C# .net 6.0

Comment: Check the change on my post.

Comment: `var x = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` is shorter and simpler